# : character error in a grep command using ansible shell module

Tags: shell, ansible

Im trying to find a certain key value pair in a json file but ansible doesn't seem to like the : character...
I tried escaping all the characters without success... any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
- name: Check if file contains the entry KEY VAL
  shell: cat PATH/dummy_file.file | grep  "\"KEY\": \"VAL\""
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  failed_when: false
  register: cat_result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the whole shell line:

```
 shell: 'cat PATH/dummy_file.file | grep "\"KEY\": \"VAL\""'
```